# SQL Server, C#, ntext, nvarchar, how to use not equal to

Tags: c#, sql-server

To begin with I want to say that I'm aware that this could be solved by column datatype changes in the database, but that is not an option, since the database is from an older system which is not under my control.

I want to query the database and find something like:

```
where Field1<>@Field1Value Or Field2<>@Field2Value
```

Where `Field1` and `Field2` are `nvarchar` and `ntext` columns.

Is there a way to do this with SQL?

Thank you.

Comment: sounds like you need to query the database using SQLCommand do you have any C# Code that you have created that you can show or are you trying to write Stored Procedure or Query code that runs on the SQL Database..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LIKE` is the operator you are looking for.

You can simply query your columns using:

```
where column2 NOT LIKE <value1>
```

This will return the same results as `<>` does for other columns.

By the way, the `ntext datatype` will no longer be supported in future sql-server versions.

See [MSDN ntext deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Cast the ntext to an nvarchar:

```
cast(Field1 as nvarchar(max))
```